# Swift textview scrollRangeToVisible is not working inside textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: swift, autolayout, textview, constraints, scrollview

I'm building a chat and when I type a message and press send button textview is positioning at the bottom, like I want. But when I dismiss keyboard and click to type another message the textview is positioning at the top, I would like at the bottom. I try to put scrollRangeToVisible inside textFieldDidBeginEditing but is not working.

Follow the code:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date as Date)
    let complement = "Sender (" + String(describing: components.hour!) + ":" + String(describing: components.minute!) + ") "
    self.chatTextView.text = (self.chatTextView.text)! + complement + self.textMessage.text! + "\n\n"
    self.textMessage.text = ""
    chatTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    let stringLength:Int = self.chatTextView.text.characters.count
    self.chatTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(stringLength-1, 0))
}

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:250),animated: true)
    heightChatTextConstraint.constant = heightChatTextConstraint.constant - 250
    let stringLength:Int = self.chatTextView.text.characters.count
    self.chatTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(stringLength-1, 0))
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:0),animated: true)
    heightChatTextConstraint.constant = heightChatTextConstraint.constant + 250
}
```

Follow image working fine (when I type one message after another without dismiss keyboard):

[image]

Follow image not working (After I dismiss keyboard and click to type a new message, textview is not going to the bottom):

[image]

Comment: Do you have the delegate setup?

Comment: @Ro4ch I set delegate for textfield: self.text Message.delegate = self, not for textView